# Does this list every Chrome extension/addin that may leak privacy?

Tags: web-browser, privacy, chrome, browser-extensions

I am looking for a simple list of all extensions, preference, custom processes, and "flags" that may disclose a user's privacy or other details to a 3rd party.

To that end, I discovered: `chrome://net-internals/#modules` which seems to accomplish this.

Is that URL a complete, full, and accurate list of every process within Chrome that may leak privacy related information?

I disabled most of my services and think this is almost the bare-minimum number of processes needed in Chrome.  Where can I get more information about some of these processes, so I can disable them?

```
ID                                  App     Enabled Name    Version Description
ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb    false   true    Web Store   0.2 Discover great apps, games, extensions and themes for Google Chrome.
eemcgdkfndhakfknompkggombfjjjeno    false   true    Bookmark Manager    0.1 Bookmark Manager
eemlkeanncmjljgehlbplemhmdmalhdc    true    true    Chrome Connectivity Diagnostics 1.1.3   
ennkphjdgehloodpbhlhldgbnhmacadg    true    true    Settings    0.2 Settings
gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp    true    false   Chrome Remote Desktop   42.0.2311.37    Access other computers or allow another user to access your computer securely over the Internet.
gfdkimpbcpahaombhbimeihdjnejgicl    true    true    Feedback    1.0 User feedback extension
gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik    false   true    Bookmark Manager    2.2015.506.11355    Bookmark Manager
kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd    false   true    CryptoTokenExtension    0.9.20  CryptoToken Component Extension
lccekmodgklaepjeofjdjpbminllajkg    false   true    Chrome Hotword Shared Module    0.3.0.2 Support files for Chrome Hotwording.
mfehgcgbbipciphmccgaenjidiccnmng    false   true    Cloud Print 0.1 Cloud Print
mgndgikekgjfcpckkfioiadnlibdjbkf    false   true    Chrome  0.1 A fast, simple, and secure web browser, built for the modern web.
mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai    false   true    Chrome PDF Viewer   1   
nbpagnldghgfoolbancepceaanlmhfmd    false   true    Hotword triggering  0.0.1.4 
neajdppkdcdipfabeoofebfddakdcjhd    false   true    Google Network Speech   1.0 Component extension providing speech via the Google network text-to-speech service.
nkeimhogjdpnpccoofpliimaahmaaome    false   true    Google+ Hangouts    1.0 
nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda    true    true    Google Wallet   0.1.1.0 Google Wallet for digital goods
ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc    true    true    Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool 0.1.18  Develop and Debug Chrome Apps & Extensions.
pafkbggdmjlpgkdkcbjmhmfcdpncadgh    false   true    Google Now  1.2.0.1 Integrates Google Now into Chrome.
pfboblefjcgdjicmnffhdgionmgcdmne    false   true    FIDO U2F (Universal 2nd Factor) extension   0.9.6   Provides the FIDO U2F APIs for authentication. PRE-RELEASE
```

Comment: "Hotword triggering" I don't know what it is but even the name suggest some advertising/analytics nastyness. If I were you I'd just switch to Firefox right away and disable the share button and "Firefox Hello" nonsense.

Comment: @André: It's the "OK Google" hotword thing. Not everything which sounds suspicious is dangerous and not everything  which sound innocent is safe.